# Detect that you are on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

What is the most reliable and simple way to detect, from within the host, that it's running in EC2 ?

The goal is to apply some changes on boot and move some of the things in the /mnt partition (because of disk space). Because it happens directly after the OS image has been instantiated there isn't a lot of software installed (eg: curl is missing on the Ubuntu AMIs).

Comment: Why would you not know you are running on EC2 in the first place?

Comment: rDNS the IP address...

Comment: @NathanC - that doesn't work in a VPCed instance.

Comment: @EEAA True, but that wasn't mentioned.

Comment: Thanks guys. @EEAA: If you ship an install script you don't know where it's going to execute. It's not an end-goal but detecting EC2 is still useful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into chef's ohai code, I can see that they use two checks: the existence of a http server on 169.254.169.254 and the existence of fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff in the arp table.

This can be simulated like that:

```
arp | grep fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff && wget -t 1 -T 2 -S --spider http://169.254.169.254/1.0/
```

Comment: It should be noted that `169.254.169.254` is also available in EC2-alike infrastructures like Eucalyptus, not just EC2 proper.